# Delphi Indy - Eidconnclosedgracefully makes socket unusable

Tags: delphi, http, sockets, delphi-2010, indy

Scenario:

Delphi 2010 running the latest Indy version from svn trunk.

I have an application that uses a idHTTP to send http requests. This idHTTP is created only once and kept in memory as long as the application is running. I send a lot of web requests to the same http server (which is also an application developed by me).

I am using keep-alive to keep the socket connected.

After several requests, I get an `EIdConnClosedGracefully` on the client side, and no mather what I do after I get this exception, **every follow request to the same server generates the same exception**.

I have tried to disconnect, close the socket, clear the IOHandler buffer and nothing worked.

If I destroy the IdHttp object and recreate it after the exception occurs, everything works fine. But that is not what i want because I need to be connected to the server all the time (to avoid TIME_WAITS and so on).

Does anyone know how to handle `EIdConnClosedGracefully` exception on the client side and make the idHttp works after that exception occurs?

**EDIT**

I developed the web server myself, and i am sure not disconnecting after a client request. I know that this exception is ok, **but what is not ok is the socket become unusable after that**. Indy should recovery from this exception, disconnecting the socket and reconnecting it when needed. As I said, this exception is being shown to the user, not only on Delphis IDE. What i really need is an way of after getting this exception, i must be able to continue using this socket. –

Comment: Note: you can't create over 6 connection to 1 http server. All other connections will be closed by server.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I am not using threads, i am sending only 1 request at time.

Comment: @Marcus i cant post the full code here because it is really big. I am using Post() method. It is not a issue on the server side afaik.

Comment: Sorry, it is not true. I messed up it with Qt QNetworkAccessManager

Comment: Rafael, put the "Post" into a try-except and run it outside of the IDE, see if the problem persist, I assume that the server is closing the connection for some reason, also, you might want to check if the connection is closed for some "special" reason at the same post all the time, maybe you're not making the "right" request?

Comment: Calling `TIdHTTP.Disconnect(False)` and `TIdHTTP.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear()` should be all you need to recover. If it is not working, then please provide the call stack log when the subsequent exceptions are being raised.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `TIdHTTP.Disconnect(False)` and `TIdHTTP.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear()` should be all you need to recover.

Comment: Thanks Remy. That was plain and simple.

Comment: @Remy, would you explain why use `False` for the `ANotifyPeer` parameter for the Disconnect method? Thanks.

Comment: @EdwinYip: It bypasses an internal call to `Connected()`, which used to raise an exception in some corner cases. I think that was fixed a while back ago, though.